# Whether $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, and let x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the following statements:
>
> (I) $Ax$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> (II) $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Which of the above statements is/are always true?

I'm sure that statement $(I)$ is always true. But I'm not sure about statement $(II)$. Need some help here thanks.

Comment: Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} &\dots&a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \ &\dots&a_{2n} \\ \vdots \\a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\dots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\\vdots \\ x_n\end{pmatrix}$. 

Do you mean $Ax=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}x_1+\dots +a_{1n}x_n \\ a_{21}x_1+\dots +a_{2n}x_n \\\vdots \\ a_{n1}x_1+\dots +a_{nn}x_n\end{pmatrix}=x_1\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}\\ a_{21} \\\vdots \\ a_{n1}\end{pmatrix} +x_2\begin{pmatrix} a_{12}\\ a_{22} \\\vdots \\ a_{n2}\end{pmatrix}+\dots +x_n\begin{pmatrix} a_{1n}\\ a_{2n} \\\vdots \\ a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR yes, just a little unsure if it will be always true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} &\dots&a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \ &\dots&a_{2n} \\ \vdots \\a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\dots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\\vdots \\ x_n\end{pmatrix}$.

Then it always happen that $Ax$ can be written as (Just by multiplication definition)

$$Ax=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}x_1+\dots +a_{1n}x_n \\ a_{21}x_1+\dots +a_{2n}x_n \\\vdots \\ a_{n1}x_1+\dots +a_{nn}x_n\end{pmatrix}=x_1\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}\\ a_{21} \\\vdots \\ a_{n1}\end{pmatrix} +x_2\begin{pmatrix} a_{12}\\ a_{22} \\\vdots \\ a_{n2}\end{pmatrix}+\dots +x_n\begin{pmatrix} a_{1n}\\ a_{2n} \\\vdots \\ a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$ and I hope this is you asking for!

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of matrix products, $\textbf{A}_{n\times n}\cdot \textbf{x}_{n\times 1} = \textbf{B}_{n\times 1} \in \Bbb R^n$.

Also, $b_i = \prod_{j=0}^n x_j a_{ij}$.  Note that if $\vec{a_i}$ is the column vector and $x_1\vec{a_1}+...+x_n\vec{a_n} = \textbf{C}_{n\times 1}$, since $\vec{a_i} = (a_{1i}, a_{2i}, ...)$, then $c_i = x_1 a_{i1} + x_2 a_{i2} + ...$ = $b_n$. Thus $\textbf{B} = \textbf{C}$, that satistifies condition (II). $\square$